# Extract matching tuples in bag in PIG

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I have raw data in bag:

```
{(id,35821),(lang,en-US),(pf_1,us)}
{(path,/ybe/wer),(id,23481),(lang,en-US),(intl,us),(pf_1,yahoo),(pf_3,test)}
{(id,98234),(lang,ir-IL),(pf_1,il),(pf_2,werasdf|dfsas)}
```

How could I extract the tuples whose column 1 matches id and pf_*?

The output I want:

```
{(id,35821),(pf_1,us)}
{(id,23481),(pf_1,yahoo),(pf_3,test)}
{(id,98234),(pf_1,il),(pf_2,werasdf|dfsas)}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to process the inner bag (a bag in a format like `OUTER_BAG: {INNER_BAG: {(e:int)}}`) you are going to have to use a [nested `FOREACH`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#nestedblock).  This will allow you to preform operations over the tuples in the inner bag.

For example, you are going to want to do something like:

```
-- A: {inner_bag: {(val1: chararray, val2: chararray)}}

B = FOREACH A {
        filtered_bags = FILTER inner_bag BY val1 matches '^(id|pf_).*' ;
    GENERATE filtered_bags ;
}
```